# Overwriting the file results in 0 bytes

Tags: bash, macos

I want to change the encoding of a txt file.

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t UTF-8 filename.txt > filename.txt
```

I don't want to change the filename but when i do it that way i get a 0 byte file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting 0 bytes because you're overwriting your input file.

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t UTF-8 filename.txt > output.txt &&
  mv output.txt filename.txt
```

Comment: More specifically, `> filename.txt` causes the shell to open (and truncate) the file before it starts `iconv`.

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner and @Garret Hyde point out, the shell parses the I/O redirections before anything else and is over-writing `filename.txt` before iconv gets a chance to read it. You will have to do this operation in two steps:

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t UTF-8 filename.txt > tmpfile.txt &&
  mv tmpfile.txt filename.txt
```

The `&&` will ensure that the over-writing of the original file only happens if the iconv command succeeds.